# How to convert SVN (Subversion) to Hg (Mercurial) on Windows?

Tags: svn, mercurial, clone, tortoisehg, hgsubversion

I am using Windows xp 32 bit and i am using TortoiseHg and I want to clone a file from Codeplex but when I try to clone the sourcecode, I got an error says

> 'https://wbfsmanager.svn.codeplex.com/svn?cmd=capabilities/?cmd=capabilities/?cmd=between&pairs=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000000000000000000000000000000000/' does not appear to be an hg repository:

So how can I convert it to a Hg format?

Comment: Have you read https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should normally [use TortoiseSVN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeplex/archive/2008/09/14/codeplex-launches-support-for-tortoisesvn.aspx) to checkout a Subversion repository from Codeplex via their SvnBridge. If it's your own project, then you can also create it as a *Mercurial* repository instead of a Subversion repository.

However, if you *really* want to use Mercurial to clone from Subversion, then you need more than just standard Mercurial: you need to use [hgsubversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/). Please see [my hgsubversion guide](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/hgsubversion/) for some help.